# Tracking email campaign opens with mailgun tags using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, mailgun

I would like to use and manage Email o:tags using SMTP method but I could not find any document  or help supporting  it. I am using phpmailer. Please guide me adding o:tags using phpmailer while sending an email so I can track the emails in analysis section.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, but ran into the same problem and figured it out:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();

$mailer->addCustomHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', 'first_tag');
```

It is [documented here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-smtp) as the first entry of the "Passing Sending Options" of SMTP.

This can go up to a maximum of 3 per mail and a total of 4000 different tags:

```
$mailer->addCustomHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', 'second_tag');

$mailer->addCustomHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', 'third_tag');
```

> Note: By default, each account is allowed a maximum of 4,000 tags. Any tags created after the 4,000 tag limit are dropped. If more tags are needed, please contact our support team by creating a support ticket here.

The tags are case insensitive, have a maximum length of 128 characters and must be completely ascii.

[Tagging documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#tagging)